# I would like to get a date with strtotime. last fri or sat or sun on a month

Tags: php

I would like to get a date with strtotime.

A last Friday of a month and Saturday and Sunday if the month has sat and Sunday after last Friday.

How should I get it?

e.g.  Aug 2021.
LastFriDay = 27 28 =sat 29 = sun.
I want to fetch “29. Aug”

e.g.  July 2021.
LastFriday = 30 31 = sat. 1.Sep = sun
Then I want to fetch 31.Aug.

e.g Sep 2022
LastFriday  = 30.  1.Oct = sat
Then  The date should be 30.sep

```
 $friOrSatOrSun = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last fri of this month", strtotime($a_certain_day_of_month)));
```

Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: For a certain month (e.g. Aug) in a year (e.g. 2021), you can determine the last day of this month/year . Use a loop to reduce this date by ONE day at the end of every iteration ;  check whether it is Fri OR Sat OR Sun at the start of the loop. If the answer is yes, then quit the loop and the date is what you want.