# I am looking for a way to compare months in PHP

Tags: php

How should I compare months of two date data?

Is there any a good way? My approach gave me

> ErrorException A non well formed numeric value encountered

I tried this to solve this.
[I would like to get a date with strtotime. last fri or sat or sun on a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356474/i-would-like-to-get-a-date-with-strtotime-last-fri-or-sat-or-sun-on-a-month?noredirect=1#comment120809325_68356474)

```
$last_Date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last fri of  next month", strtotime($request->deli_date)));
$last_Date_add1day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last fri of next month +1 day", strtotime($request->deli_date)));
if(date("n", $last_Date) == date("n", $last_Date_add1day)){
    $last_Date_add2day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last fri of next month +2 day", strtotime($request->deli_date)));
    if(date("n", $last_Date_add1day) == date("n",$last_Date_add2day)){
        $last_Date = $last_Date_add2day;
    }else{
        $last_Date = $last_Date_add1day;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop `date('Y-m-d')` from anywhere where you use `strtotime`. It converts timestamp (int) to formatted date (string) and you feed it into parameter that requires INT

```php
$last_Date = strtotime("last fri of  next month", strtotime($request->deli_date));
$last_Date_add1day = strtotime("last fri of next month +1 day", strtotime($request->deli_date));

if(date("n", $last_Date) == date("n", $last_Date_add1day))
{
    $last_Date_add2day = strtotime("last fri of next month +2 day", strtotime($request->deli_date));
    if(date("n", $last_Date_add1day) == date("n", $last_Date_add2day)){
        $last_Date = $last_Date_add2day;
    }
    else
    {
        $last_Date = $last_Date_add1day;
    }
}
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e96992f12e0e105a324d40ae81bf6ba47e9064ec)